# Azure Pipeline MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines

I am new to the whole azure pipeline. I have a project running on .net framework and want to create YAML with MSBuild in order to perform the following:

1. Cleaning solution
2. Restore Nuget Package
3. Build Solution
4. Run Unit Test (in different folder)
5. Package and publish

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Since you are new here, 1) switch to GitHub Actions if you can. 2) tons of examples over the internet https://timheuer.com/blog/building-net-framework-apps-using-github-actions/ If you still prefer Azure Pipelines https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use YAML in Azure DevOps Pipeline, you could create a new YAML pipeline from scratch:

[image]

To add more tasks in the pipeline, you could click `Show assistant` and select the tasks you need:

[image]

The .yml file may look like below:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'   

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Since you are new to Azure DevOps and want to start with YAML, please see our [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops) documentation for great getting started guides and examples. More information, you could refer to [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) documentation. You can also find additional documentation and samples in [azure-pipelines-yaml](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml) GitHub repo.